# Solving one equation for two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a theorem that states that you need $N$ equations to solve for $N$ unknowns?

If I had the following equality,

$$x^25^y = 10125$$

isn't it possible to deduce that $x = 9$ and $y = 3$ simply by looking at prime factors?

Are there multiple solutions when there are $N$ unknowns and less than $N$ equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system of **linear** equations is regular (which is a special case of having $n$ equations with $n$ unknown), it is guaranteed to have a unique solution.

Your equation above is non-linear, and has an additional constraint that you want only non-negative integer solutions. Of course, you cannot deduce much about such a case only from the number of equations and unknowns.

For example $x^2y^7 = 2$ will have no integer solutions, while $x^2y^2 = 2^{32}$ will have lots of integer solutions.

Comment: How did you figure out that there is a constraint that the `x` and `y` have to be positive integers?

Comment: I assumed because you claimed that "x = 9 and y = 3 simply by looking at prime factors". If this is not the case, then pick any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and you'll get $$y = \log_5 \frac{10125}{x^2}.$$ Or pick any $y$ and you'll get $$x = \pm\sqrt{10125/5^y}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are infinitely many solutions to this equation.  However, there are only two unique solutions for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$.  This can, indeed, be found by unique prime factorization.  $10125=3^4\cdot5^3=x^2\cdot5^y$.  Thus, the solution sets are $(x,y)=(9,3),(45,1)$